# org.mockito.internal.matchers.LocalizedMatcher cannot be cast to org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher with "any" matcher when running "activator test"

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

I'm having an error in one of my specs2 tests. The project is implemented with Play!Framework (Scala).

This is my test:

```
class AmazonEmailSenderSpec extends Specification with Mockito {
    "AmazonEmailSenderSpec#sendEmail" should {
        "Send Email with correct data" in {

          val client = mock[AmazonSimpleEmailServiceAsyncClient]
          val emailSender = new AmazonEmailSender(client)

          emailSender.sendEmail(Email(subject, content, from, to, cc))

          val captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[SendEmailRequest])
          there was one(client).sendEmail(captor.capture)

          val sendEmailRequest: SendEmailRequest = captor.getValue
        }
      }
}
```

This test works fine if I run it on intellij, but somehow, it fails when I run it on the console using the play activator:

```
activator test
```

I get:

```
[info] AmazonEmailSenderSpec#sendEmail should
[error]   ! Send Email with correct data
[error]    org.mockito.internal.matchers.LocalizedMatcher cannot be cast to org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher (ArgumentsComparator.java:25)
[error] org.mockito.internal.invocation.ArgumentsComparator.argumentsMatch(ArgumentsComparator.java:25)
[error] org.mockito.internal.invocation.ArgumentsComparator.argumentsMatch(ArgumentsComparator.java:17)
[error] org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher.matches(InvocationMatcher.java:56)
[error] org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationsFinder$RemoveNotMatching.isOut(InvocationsFinder.java:145)
[error] org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationsFinder$RemoveNotMatching.isOut(InvocationsFinder.java:137)
[error] org.mockito.internal.util.collections.ListUtil.filter(ListUtil.java:16)
[error] org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationsFinder.findInvocations(InvocationsFinder.java:20)
[error] org.mockito.internal.verification.checkers.MissingInvocationChecker.check(MissingInvocationChecker.java:32)
[error] org.mockito.internal.verification.Times.verify(Times.java:36)
[error] org.mockito.internal.verification.MockAwareVerificationMode.verify(MockAwareVerificationMode.java:21)
[error] org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:76)
[error] org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
[error] org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:37)
[error] org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:36)
[error] org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.access$000(MockMethodInterceptor.java:17)
[error] org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptSuperCallable(MockMethodInterceptor.java:96)
[error] com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceAsyncClient$MockitoMock$1778874818.sendEmail(Unknown Source)
[error] integration.email.AmazonEmailSenderSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(AmazonEmailSenderSpec.scala:27)
[error] integration.email.AmazonEmailSenderSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(AmazonEmailSenderSpec.scala:27)
[error] integration.email.AmazonEmailSenderSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(AmazonEmailSenderSpec.scala:27)
[error] integration.email.AmazonEmailSenderSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(AmazonEmailSenderSpec.scala:19)
```

I can't understand why a LocalizedMatcher is being used by activator when an ArgumentMatcher should be used instead.

The signature to the method I'm trying to match is:

```
public SendEmailResult sendEmail(SendEmailRequest sendEmailRequest)
```

Couldn't really find any hints on google. Any ideas? Am I missing something really silly?

Comment: I haven't really been able to solve this specific problem, but just had the same exception happening to me in another situation and I was able to identify that it was caused by using any: "myService.getProfile(any[String]) returns None". By not being lazy and specifying the actual parameter for getProfile, I solved the issue for this particular problem (not for the original question, though, so any tips would be welcome)

Comment: what is the version of the mockito lib? I'm having the same issue with a mixed java/scala project using mockito `2.7.11`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I just happened to run into the same issue in 2017:

A solution that worked for me (JUnit/Specs2, in a mixed Java/Scala) project:

I forced mockito to use the latest version `2.7.11`. But I also had a dependency on `org.specs2:specs2-mock_2.12:3.8.6` which is still based on mockito `1.9.5`. See [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.specs2/specs2-mock_2.12/3.8.8).
Somewhere here lies the problem. I removed the dependency on `specs2-mock` and Specs2's mockito syntax sugar and replaced it with plain mockito code. Voila! The error mentioned above was gone.

Comment: I had the same problem, but solved it by removing Mockito and instead importing `org.specs2.mock.Mockito` and using that syntax. The syntax is slightly different, but there's pretty good documentation [here](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.8.9/org.specs2.guide.UseMockito.html).